# DC motor operation with a varying voltage

Tags: pwm

So I was studying PWM control of DC motors and it got me confused.Here the input is pulsated.This will obviously turn the motor fully on or fully off.Wouldn't this create vibrations?I know pulse waveform has an average value but the instantaneous value (it falls to zero in between pulses) is getting me confused..

Comment: The motor wouldn't instantly stop when the voltage drops. It'll only cause a short loss of "power". But PWM is so fast you will never be able to see this (without an ossiloscope).

Comment: How is PWM fast?Do you mean it has very large duty cycle?Because I think only then the voltage won't drop instantaneously.

Comment: It has a very high frequency, the DC motor will be switched on/off more as 1000 times per second. Which won't be noticable in the motors' behaviour. But the average power towards the motor will be lower.

Comment: What if the frequency was low (hypothetically),would the motor stop in between?

Comment: Yes, if you switch the power on/off once a sec you'll see it gaining speed one second and then decelerating (free running) the other second. Though you have to take care, if your PWM is too fast for the motor it might cause some issues. And when there is a big load on the motor I guess it could actually stutter/vibrate.

Answer (score 1):

The motor experiences torque ripple as it commutates and the coils switch.

Usually the PWM is fast enough that the motor inductance smooths out the current, and torque is proportional to current. If the PWM frequency is low you can get 'vibrations' that cause audible noise from the motor. For example, some older electric streetcars made whining noises when accelerating.

[image]

The really old ones used carbon pile controls and were relatively quiet (but wasteful of energy).

Comment: Exactly, compare the freq of the rotor (say.. 20Hz) to the time constant of the stator inductance and then look at the PWM freq (which is probably 10kHz). Is there some component? sure but it should be insignificant (if designed correctly) when the rotor inertia acts as a mechanical filter to torque ripple